# Select previous dates until today and disable all future days in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, datepicker, codeigniter-2

How can I enable a selection of previous days from today and disable the future dates in my CodeIgniter view? Now my code is displaying all the future dates and has disabled all the previous dates. My code is as below:

```html
<script>
var elem = document.getElementById("security_question_1");

elem.onchange = function() {
    var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("showMe");
    hiddenDiv.style.display = (this.value == "Absconding") ? "none":"none";
    hiddenDiv.style.display = (this.value == "Termination") ? "none":"block";
    hiddenDiv.style.display = (this.value == "Employee Initiated") ? "none":"block";
};

function parseDate(str) {
    var mdy = str.split('/')
    return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
}

function daydiff(first, second) {
    return Math.round((second-first)/(1000*60*60*24));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#startdt").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        yearRange: "-90:+0",
        startDate: new Date(),
        autoclose: true
    }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        $('#enddt').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
    });

    $("#sincedt").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        yearRange: "-90:-10",
        startDate: new Date(),
        autoclose: true
    }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        $('#enddt').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
    });

    $("#enddt").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        yearRange: "-90:+0"
    });

    $("#enddtt").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        yearRange: "-90:+0"
    });

    $("#enddttt").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        yearRange: "-90:+0"
    });

    $("#enddt").change(function(){
        if($("#startdt").val()!='' && $("#enddt").val()!='') {
            var startdt = $("#startdt").val();
            var enddt = $("#enddt").val();
            $("#daysleave").val(daydiff(parseDate(startdt), parseDate(enddt)));
            if($("#grievance_type").val()!='0') {
                var day_diff_today = daydiff(parseDate($("#today_dt").val()), parseDate($("#startdt").val()));

                if(((parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-min"))) &&  (parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) < parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-max"))))&&(day_diff_today > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-approvaldays")))) {
                } else {
                    $("#leaveAllowedModal").modal("show");
                }
            }
        }
    })

    $("#grievance_type").change(function() {
        if($("#startdt").val()!='' && $("#enddt").val()!='' && $("#grievance_type").val()!='0') {
            var day_diff_today = daydiff(parseDate($("#today_dt").val()), parseDate($("#startdt").val()));

            if(((parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-min"))) &&  (parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) < parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-max"))))&&(day_diff_today > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-approvaldays")))) {
            } else {
                $("#leaveAllowedModal").modal("show");
            }
        }
    })

    $(".date-picker").datepicker();

    $("#optionsRadios1").click(function() {
        $("#myLTAModal").modal("show");
    })

    $('#leaveAllowedModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        var msg = '';
        if((parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-min"))) &&  (parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) < parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-max")))) {
        } else {
            msg = msg + "You wish you apply "+$("#daysleave").val()+" day of "+$("#grievance_type option:selected").text()+". Minimum and Maximum no. of Leaves allowed to take at a time are "+$("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-min")+" and "+$("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-max")+" respectively.";
        }
        var day_diff_today = daydiff(parseDate($("#today_dt").val()), parseDate($("#startdt").val()));
        if((day_diff_today < parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-approvaldays")))) {
            msg = msg + " No. of days of prior approval needed is  " + $("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-approvaldays") + " days";
        }
        $(".allowed_text").html(msg);
    })
});
</script>
```

I want to display it here:

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Absconding Since</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="date" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" data-date-viewmode="years">
        <input placeholder="Absconding Since" class=" m-wrap col-md-8 form-control " id="startdt" type="text" name="abscondingsince" value="<?php if($row->requested_date!='') echo date("d-m-Y",$row->requested_date); ?>" required/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try `maxDate` instead of `minDate`

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: all previous dates are disabled

Comment: why are you taking var selected.date.valueOf() inside var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());? Try this var maxDate = new Date();

Comment: Nope its not working... Anyways there is no difference